# How to activate a component in angular 2 without visiting the component

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I am building an application in which I have a cart which is in different module as a component.

I am clicking on the button to add the item into the cart and in the cart component I'm subscribing to this event:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this._cartService.itemSelected$.subscribe(item => {          
     console.log("Item added into cart cart component");           
      });
}
```

But, I'm facing a problem when I have not visited the cart page and at that time when I am trying to add the item into cart then that `"Item added into cart cart component"` is not being called but after visiting the cart page its getting called when the add to cart button is called.

I am adding this from some other component which is in different module. So, I cannot able to figure out how we can make out subscribe to be called without visiting the cart component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load that component in dom in order to run ngOninit method. If you have made a selector for that component then you can simply add that selector in header or some where so as soon your application load it also load the cart component and every time you add a item to cart your component will be notified. If you don't want to do this way then you have to us resolveNgFactory to add component dynamically to the dom. Not recommended as you have to handle it for not adding it resolving it every time and make sure you destroy it manually when you empty your cart. Hope this help.